# Wordpress Migration

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-lists, nav

I have been trying to create just one page based on the Wordpress CMS called blog. Now this page created will need to be linked to my normal website which was created using the foundation framework HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

I am having no luck in linking my website to the Wordpress blog page website. I have been told to create a sub-folder within the public_html folder in Filezilla. I just can't seem to migrate both of them together.

Comment: It would be nice if someone would give me some advice

Comment: You should post more details and show what you have done exactly.

Comment: does the WordPress site works by itself ?. You will also have to update the .htaccess file. Please show the folder hierarchic yo used under public_html.

Comment: The wordpress site works. I have created one page which is called blog and want to link this page with my normal site to make the wordpress page and my normal website work together.
The folder hierarchy under my public_html is :
index.html
contact.html
aboutus.html
css folder
js folder
blog folder 
(Under this blog folder is the whole of the wordpress files and folders)